# How to enable Excel to save files (grey button)?

Tags: excel, macos, greybox

I want to be able to save my excel sheets, but the save button is greyed out and I don't know what to do. I am running the program on Mac OS Catalina 10.15.5 on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15', Mid 2015)
I am an absolute noob when it comes to Excel so I would be very very grateful if someone could help me! Down below I displayed the problem:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyBMk.png)

Answer (score 0):

your account doesn't allow editing on a mac. Might be your office plan is not active. still, write something on the exile sheet and try to save it.

Comment: Allright, yeah I already tried to save couple of spreadsheets but unfortunately the Save button is still greyed out :(

Comment: I figured it out, one needs to delete old Excel licenses